# Terraform escaping bash command substitution

Tags: terraform

When working with inline bash in terraform, I know that I have to escape interpolation with `$${foo}` and will be rendered as literal `${foo}`

What about for bash command substitions?

do i need to `$$(echo "hello")` <= `$(echo "hello")`??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you do not need to use `$$(echo "hello")`. `$(echo "hello")` is fine.

Terraform will always interpret `${...}` (with curly braces) as an indicator that it should interpolate the text between the curly braces. But sometimes you actually want the string literal `${...}`, in which case you need a way to escape that sequence, which as you pointed out can be done like this: `$${...}`.

But `$` by itself is seen as a literal by Terraform, so you can just include it without escaping it.